# Virtual machine loses network connection

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, nat, host-only

I'm having a problem with NAT and Host-Only network adapters

This are my configurations (VMnet0 has no problems): https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8of1.png

What happens?

Everytime I boot a virtual machine (in this case, I'm using Ubuntu, also tried on FreeBSD) I have network (and internet) connection, but as soon as any connection reaches the virtual machine I lose it all, it's either a ping, accessing the database, opening the webpage running with apache or any SSH connection (PuTTY or FileZilla). There's no in or out connections from that vm after that.

The network adapters are brand new as well as the virtual machine, only has installed Apache2, MySQL 5.7 and OpenSSH. The VM using NAT has OpenSSH, DHCP and DNS Server. The other VM is using VMnet3 (Host Only)

I already tried netsh winsock reset and reinstalling vmware. No success.

The only workaround I found it's restarting the network adapter or reboot the vm.

I also don't have conflicting IP addresses or mac addresses.

I've no idea what could be wrong. I last resource I'll format my computer.

I'm running VMware Workstation 16 Pro - 16.0.0 build-16894299.

My host is running Windows 10 Pro 2004

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formatting the computer didn't solve, as I imported the network settings from the backup file.

Turns out there's a problem when you define the gateway as .1, which I was doing on NAT and Ubuntu server interfaces. I switch to .2 and everything works.

Here's the tip that I found: https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/VMWare-Workstation-Pro-15-NAT-drops-after-a-few-hours/m-p/491094#M25821